# multiple background processes in a script

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, process-management

Suppose if i have a situation in which some files need to be copied and it takes long time so
i would have to go for parallel processing of the file copy.
for example it may look like this

```
for i in ipaddresslist
do

cp x y &  //running in back ground or some other process in background

done

wait  //will cause till all the files are copied or whatever process if all are finished
```

now i have used `wait`  so that all the backgroud processes are completed
but there are cases in it like

1) some file copy may happen earlier so if i have to do some processing on these files
i have to wait till all the files are copied.

2) if the copy process (or any other program running in back ground) writes to a log file
the log file could be garbled with each background process trying to write to the file
at the same time.

is there any workaround for such things,
1)i mean if i can know that this process has finished then i could start doing the rest of the processing for that particular instance of the process(say file copy) if its completed.
also, moreover writing to log files could be in orderly fashion.

please make suggestions

Comment: how do people handle such situations if they occur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If some job needs to be started after some file has been copied, just make it part of the background job:

```
(cp this /there && start job that needs this in /there) &
(cp that /here && start job that needs that in /here) &
wait
```

(the last `&` is not necessary).

Now for more complex dependencies, you could use GNU `make -j`.

```
make -j2 -f /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOF'
all: j1 j2 j3
.PHONY: cp1 cp2 cp3 j1 j2 j3 all

cp1:
    cp this /there

cp2:
    cp that /here

cp3:
    cp this /here

j1: cp1
    start job that needs this in /there

j2: cp2
    start job that needs that in /here

j3: cp1 cp3
    start job that needs this in /here and /there
EOF
```

`-j2` would run up to 2 jobs at any given time, and dependencies would be respected.

Now to avoid garbling of log files you have two main options

1. don't interleave them, that is append the content of each job one after the other.
2. try to ensure they interleave nicely, possibly tagging each line of each job to make it easier to see what job which line belongs to.

For 1, the easiest is to store each job output in a separate file and to merge them afterwards:

```
(cp this /there && start job that needs this in /there) > j1.log 2>&1 &
(cp that /here && start job that needs that in /here) > j2.log 2>&1 &
wait
cat j1.log j2.log > jobs.log
```

Another option is to use pipes to gather the output of each job and have `cat` merge them. Shell process substitution as available in `ksh`, `zsh` or `bash` can help us with that and even take care of the backgrounding:

```
j1() { cp this /there && start job that needs this in /there; }
j2() { cp that /here && start job that needs that in /here; }
cat <(j1 2>&1) <(j2 2>&1) > jobs.log
```

`j1`, `j2` and `cat` will be started concurrently and inter connected with pipes.

However note that `cat` will only start reading from the second pipe (that is written to by `j2`) after `j1` has finished. That means that if `j2` writes more logging than the size of the pipe (for instance, on Linux, typically 64kiB) `j2` will be blocked until `j1` finishes.

That can be avoided by using `sponge` from `moreutils`, like:

```
cat <(j1 2>&1) <(j2 2>&1 | sponge) > jobs.log
```

Though that would mean all the output of `j2` would be stored in memory, and cat will only start writing the output of `j2` in `jobs.log` after `j2` has finished, in which case using `pv -qB 100M` for instance may be preferable:

```
cat <(j1 2>&1) <(j2 2>&1 | pv -qB 100M) > jobs.log
```

That way `j2` would only get paused (if `j1` has not finished yet) after `100M` (plus two pipe contents) of logs have been output, and `pv` wouldn't wait for `j2` to finish before outputting to stdout.

Note that for all the above, you need to beware that once you redirect the output of most commands to a file or pipe (anything but a tty), the behavior is affected. The commands, or rather the `stdio` API of the `libc` they call (`printf`, `fputs`, `fwrite`...) detects that the output is not going to a terminal and perform an optimisation by outputting in big chunks (several kilo-bytes), while they don't do that for standard error. That means the order of the output and error messages will be affected. If that's an issue, on GNU systems or FreeBSD (at least) and for dynamically linked commands, you can use the `stdbuf` command:

```
stdbuf -oL j1 > j1.log 2>&1
```

instead of:

```
j1 > j1.log 2>&1
```

to ensure that the stdio output is line-buffered (each line of output will be written separately as soon as they are complete).

For option 2, writes to a pipe of less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes which on Linux is 4096 bytes so much larger than your average line of log, are guaranteed to be atomic, that is if two processes write to the same pipe at the same time, their 2 writes are guaranteed not to be intertwined. There's no such guarantee on regular files but I seriously doubt that 2 writes of less than 4kiB could end up intertwined on any OS or filesystem.

So if it weren't for that buffering described above and if log lines were output individually as a whole and separately, you'd have a guarantee that the lines of the output wouldn't have a piece of line of this job and a piece of line of that other job.

However, nothing prevents a command to do a flush in between two parts of a line being written (like `printf("foo"); fflush(stdout); printf("bar\n");`) and there's no buffering on stderr.

Another problem is that once the lines of all the jobs are interleaved, it's going to be hard to tell which line is for which job.

You can solve both problems by doing something like:

```
tag() { stdbuf -oL sed "s%^%$1: %"; }
{
  j1 2>&1 | tag j1 &
  j2 2>&1 | tag j2
} | cat > jobs.log
```

(note that we don't need the `wait` (and it wouldn't work anyway in most shells), because `cat` will not finish until there's nobody writing to the pipe anymore, so not until `j1` and `j2` have terminated).

Above we use `| cat` to have pipe with its atomicity guarantee. We pipe the output of each command to a command that *tags* every line with the job name. `j1` and `j2` can write their output however they want, `sed` (because of `stdbuf -oL`) will output the lines (with the tag prefix) as a whole and separately, which will guarantee the output not to be mangled.

The same note as above still applies: we're not applying `stdbuf -oL` to the commands in `j1` and `j2` so they will most likely buffer their output which may therefore be written long after it has been produced. That is even worse than in the previous case, because if you see:

```
j1: doing A
j1: doing B
j2: doing C
```

That does mean that `j1` did A before doing B, but not that it did any of them before `j2` doing C. So once again, you may need to apply `stdbuf -oL` to more commands if it's an issue.

Note that you can't apply `stdbuf` to shell functions like `j1` or `j2` above, but at least with GNU and FreeBSD stdbuf, you can use this to set `stdbuf` globally or on a per-subshell basis:

```
stdbuf_LD_PRELOAD=$(stdbuf sh -c 'export -p LD_PRELOAD')
line_buffered_output() {
  eval "$stdbuf_LD_PRELOAD"
  export _STDBUF_O=L
}
j1() (line_buffered_output; cp this /there && start...)
```

Comment: Here's a table of observed `PIPE_BUF` values on common Unix systems: http://ar.to/notes/posix#pipe-buf

Comment: Option 2 is EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Aw man... I found that this script will always exit with an exit code of `0` (success) even if one of the subprocesses fails (and i'm using `set -eo pipefail`, as well). I'm still using your nifty `tag` function, but in order to make the script fail properly, I'm using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/356154/7023816

Comment: That is such a neat trick to keep the output from being mangled! +10

Answer (score 2):

If each downloaded file need procesing, do:

```
cp whatever file; process file &
```

instead.

If you are worried that log files get garbled, perhaps you should use `syslog(3)`, perhaps through `logger(1)`. Consider using `nohup(1)` if somebody could log out (and kill background running processes indavertently).